# Seaside - clear form on re-render?

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

Is there a way to reset all of the text inputs for a page when it's re-rendered? The page keeps loading with the text from the previous rendering still in the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

That depends very much on the way you render those inputs. If you use Seaside components, then you might implement you own logic within the callback:

```
html textInput
    callback: [ :value | self setOrResetMyInputWith: value ]
    with: 'my input'.
```

`#setOrResetMyInputWith:` might then look like this:

```
setOrResetMyInputWith: aString
    myInputValue := self allCriteriaMet
        ifTrue: [ aString ]
        ifFalse: [ nil ]
```

Keep in mind that you cannot predict the order in which the callbacks will be evaluated. Therefore, it might be easier to do the check before rendering:

```
renderContentOn: html
    self checkMyInputs.
    "continue rendering process"
    ...
```

You could then simply reset your instance variables if the criteria are not satisfied.

That's for components. If you use Magritte, than Magritte's verification mechanism should take care of this. All you need to do is to enable verification in the respective descriptions.